# Shuffle 10% of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, shuffle

How can I shuffle just 10% of an array such that 90% is untouched and a random 10% is shuffled?

I apply a sorting algorithm to the array. I was thinking of using `rand()` but I'm not sure how to limit the shuffle to only 10%.

Comment: If your size of the array is 10n, find a random number n times, and shuffle those elements.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta Be careful, it's not quite that simple. That would shuffle anywhere from 10% to 20% of the elements.

Comment: I assume it would have to be 5n if n > 10 because of swapping elements?

Comment: Find a random number n times and shuffle together. Instead of rand-shuffle-rand..

Comment: @EricZ this worked, thank you. The only case it does not work is when the array is size 10, because swapping two values makes it a 20% shuffle.

Comment: No. 10% of 10 is 1. It's where 1 element is shuffled with itself. No shuffle. This is the base case. When you say to shuffle 10% of the elements, only those 10% elements are shuffled, per definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can probably be improved, but you might do something like:

```
template <typename Rnd, typename IT>
void partial_shuffle(Rnd&& rnd, IT begin, IT end, std::size_t k)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(std::distance(begin, end));
    std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0);

    // Select subset to shuffle
    std::shuffle(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), rnd);
    std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(*begin)>> subset;
    
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != k; ++i) {
        subset.push_back(*(begin + indexes[i]));   
    }

    // Shuffle the subset
    std::shuffle(subset.begin(), subset.end(), rnd);

    // place them at correct position
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != k; ++i) {
        *(begin + indexes[i]) = subset[i];
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfa3c309175b4285)

Comment: `std::shuffle` does not guarantee that the result will be a derangement. Number of elements actually shuffled may be less than `k`.

Comment: OP just state sfuffling, not derangement :-) (just have to change last shuffle by a derangement algorithm).